# How to retrain the model that is generated by AutoML

Tags: ml.net, automl, ml.net-model-builder

I just started to learn machine learning.
And I am using AutoML features of ML.NET.
Following code can train my model successfully.
But, I would like to retrain it with a new dataset.
How can I do that?

```cs
var data = _context.Data.LoadFromTextFile<ModelInput>(
    path: trainFilePath,
    separatorChar: '~',
    hasHeader: true,
    allowQuoting: true,
    trimWhitespace: true);

_schema = data.Schema;

var trainTestSplit = _context.Data.TrainTestSplit(data, testFraction: 0.2);

MulticlassExperimentSettings settings = new()
{
    OptimizingMetric = MulticlassClassificationMetric.MicroAccuracy,
    MaxExperimentTimeInSeconds = secondsToTrain
};

var experiment =
    _context.Auto().CreateMulticlassClassificationExperiment(settings);

var result =
    experiment.Execute(
        trainData: trainTestSplit.TrainSet,
        validationData: trainTestSplit.TestSet,
        labelColumnName: nameof(ModelInput.Status),
        preFeaturizer: null,
        progressHandler: new MulticlassConsoleProgressReporter());

_model = result.BestRun.Model;

return result.BestRun;
```

I would like to have shorter re-training time.